# Control automatically scrolls back when using mousewheel

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have created a control and I am experiencing a weird problem. When I use the mousewheel to scroll, the view is adjusted, but when I move the mouse, the scrollbar jumps back to its original position.

However, when I click on the scrollbar and drag the bar up or down and then use the mousewheel, the problem is gone.

I'd like to post some code, but I have no idea what code to paste. This is the code that handles the scrollbar visibility:

```
protected override void SetBoundsCore(int x, int y, int width, int height, BoundsSpecified specified)
{
    base.SetBoundsCore(x, y, ControlWidth, ControlHeight, specified);
}
```

`ControlWidth` and `ControlHeight` are custom properties to calculate the width and height of the control.

Edit 1:
class signature:

```
public partial class TimeLineScheduleControl : UserControl
```

Edit 2:

I've noticed in the Form load (where the control is on), the `Y` value of the  `AutoScrollPosition` is set to -51 instead of 0.

Comment: You should try a different mouse to see if that solves the problem.

Comment: can we see the full Class signature of this .. need to see what control the class is inheriting from

Comment: @PeteWilson I've tried a different mouse, but still have the problem

Answer (score 0):

This is what your Code should look like from the Class level and it should work because you are overriding the initial base method
I am posting this just as an example so you have something to follow.. 
try a reboot if it doesn't work or a new mouse.. is this a usb / usb infra-red mouse.??

```
public class YourClass : UserControl
{
    protected override void SetBoundsCore(int x, int y, int width, int height, BoundsSpecified specified)
    {
        if (height > 35)
        {
            height = 35;
        }
        base.SetBoundsCore(x, y, width, height, specified);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried a reboot and I've tried a different mouse. Both didn't had success. My control inherits from `UserControl`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I feel very dumb right now. This one you would never had guessed.

The form the control resides on, was registered to the `MouseMove` of the control. When the mouse move got triggered, I set the `Text` property of a label. This label was on top of my form. So when I use the mousewheel to scroll, and later the mouse move triggered, the scrollbar jumped back for some reason.

No I don't use the mouse move event any more and everything works as expected...